# Adding a user control causes form to throw resources error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

So, I have a user control UcEx which inherits from Uc. Uc has other custom controls and forms, such as MyTree (a TreeView). MyTree and Uc have localized strings located in an assembly MyResources in the file Common.resx. UcEx is part of another form MainForm.

In this situation everything looks fine, but when I add a new MyTree to the UcEx, which already has 4 inherited objects of type MyTree from Uc, MainForm [design] throws an error:

{Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "MyResources.Common.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyResources" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.}

I don't understand this since all the other MyTree-s that are already there don't cause any error.
It's not a problem of namespace or assembly name or missing a resource file, so I have no idea where to go from here...
Also when I run a debug, no exception is thrown.

EDIT1: I have already tried changing **Build Action** to **Embedded Resource** and **Custom Tool** as **ResXFileCodeGenerator**

Answer (score 0):

Change the BuildAction of your ResourseFile(Common.resx) to EmbededResource and try.

Comment: I have already tried and also to set Custom tool as ResXFileCodeGenerator